# Why do I get this error: _mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h'?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I'm on a windows computer running Python 3.6 and django version 2.0.7. I've created a virtual environment using virtualenv and I'd like to use mysql, so I tried installing it by using pip like so...

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

That throws me the error above. I've looked up possible solutions on github and stackoverflow but most of them have to do with other files, not "mysql.h". Either way though, I've tried those solutions but neither seems to work for this case. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
The full error message looks like this...

```
_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such 
file or directory  
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

If it is of any significance, I am using git bash as my terminal.

Comment: Did you install the MySQL client on your *system* (The Python client is just a wrapper).

Comment: Yes. I have MySQL 5.6 installed on my system.